# How to call a shell script file with variable argument through python

Tags: bash, python

I am calling a shell script file through a python command. `Filename1` is a variable I have created in my standalone python program storing the actual value of filename. How do I write it to execute the 2nd statement below as `Filename` variable doesn't work here. If I keep the actual filename, the shell script file gets executed through second statement.

I need to automate this and cannot hardcode the actual filename. Thus, I want if by any chance the variable can be accessed in 2nd statement.

```
import os
os.system('sh uploadPDFContentFile.sh Filename1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html) module.

```
>>> subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])  # doesn't capture output
CompletedProcess(args=['ls', '-l'], returncode=0)
```

The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function.

But, you may use string substitution:

```
call_with_args = "./script2.py '%s' '%s'" % (str(arg1), str(arg2))
os.system(call_with_args)
```

Or string [format](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-examples)

```
>>> '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')
'a, b, c'
```